# Import Packages Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to programming and computer science in general. I've looked around and [Atomic Kotlin](https://www.atomickotlin.com/exercises/) seems to be the most organized and comprehensive course for new learners. I'm using Android Studio to learn how to program.

When I get to `Introduction to Objects > Testing` the package `atomictest` doesn't import for any of the following exercises.

I have created a sample program to check if the package and import tools worked in general and the tools worked fine. Then, I tried to see if IntelliJ IDEA had the same issue with the course and importing `atomictest` worked just fine. So it seems that there is a compatibility issue or a referencing issue with Android Studio and Atomic Kotlin.

I went into the `Packages` portion of the project tree and went to the actual *.kt file containing the package and it checks out.

[Here's what the error looks like within the Android Studio IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Kfc.jpg)

I could continue with IntelliJ but I want to learn using Android Studio. Why is this issue happening and how do I fix it? Thank you in advance.